# How to sort NSArray items into groups based on the same object order in a different NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sorting, nsarray

I have an NSArray of unique UUIDs sorted in the proper order. I also have another NSArray of bookmarks with a UUID encoding. I would like to sort my NSArray of bookmarks based on their UUID property into groups.

For example, I have an NSArray: @[@"uuid1", @"uuid3", @"uuid2"] that has been sorted into this particular order. Now the other NSArray must sort all of its bookmarks in the same order as the first NSArray above.

So the second NSArray is: @[@"bookmark1", @"bookmark2", @"bookmark3", ...etc.]

Say bookmark 1 has the UUID property encoded as uuid2, bookmark 2 has the UUID encoding of uuid 1, but the bookmark 3 has encoding of uuid3. How can I sort and group these bookmarks so that it would be: @[@"bookmark2", @"bookmark3", @"bookmark1"]?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you open for suggestions on how to achieve this in a better and more efficient way without using 2 arrays?

Comment: Yes, that would probably be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get rid of the second array and use a dictionary instead, which is keyed on the UUID.

```
NSArray *sortedIDs = @[ @"uuid1", @"uuid3", @"uuid2", ];

NSDictionary *items = @{
  @"uuid1" : @[ bookmark1 ],
  @"uuid2" : @[ bookmark2 ],
  @"uuid3" : @[ bookmark3 ],
};
```

Now when you want the second bookmark you can access it with

```
NSArray *bookmarksForUUID = items[sortedIDs[1]];
```

---

If you wanted to build the structure above you could add a category like the below to `NSArray`

```
- (NSDictionary *)pas_groupBy:(id (^)(id object))block;
{
  NSParameterAssert(block);

  NSMutableDictionary *groupedDictionary = NSMutableDictionary.new;

  for (id object in self) {
    id key = block(object);
    if (groupedDictionary[key]) {
      [groupedDictionary[key] addObject:object];
    } else {
      groupedDictionary[key] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:object];
    }
  }

  return groupedDictionary;
}
```

Then assuming your bookmark objects look something like

```
@interface Bookmark : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *UUID;
// other properties
// other properties

@end
```

You can use the category like this

```
NSDictionary *bookmarksMappedBySection = ({
  return [bookmarks pas_groupBy:^(Bookmark *bookmark) {
    return bookmark.UUID;
  };
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's possible to have multiple bookmarks encoded with the same UUID. Although this would probably work well if that wasn't the case.

Comment: How is a "Universally unique identifier" not unique? That sounds like a design issue

Comment: The UUID is identifying a particular device generated on a per install basis. I'm not using the UUID to identify bookmarks, rather associating a set of bookmarks to a particular device, to recognize what page a particular device on the same iCloud account has visited.

Comment: If two items have the same UUID how should they be sorted? Could they be stored in an array/set under the UUID as a key?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, that seems like it would work. My section header titles are device names corresponding to their respective UUID, so the goal is to accurately place the correct History entries in their respective section. That's why I mentioned that I already know the order the UUIDs should be in, I just need a way of placing the correct Bookmark object in the correct section.

Comment: Exactly the above would give you a way of sectioning by a key. Then you can use your ordered array to index into the dictionary to retrieve a section. See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Create a class `Bookmark`. Add both the UUIDs and title as properties to this class. Now you can have just one array which holds objects of class `Bookmark` and each one will have access to its UUID and title (as well as any other properties you might want to add later on).

```
@interface Bookmark: NSObject 

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *uuid;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *title;

@end
```

Now if you have `NSArray` (lets call it `myBookmarks`) you can do the following:

```
for (Bookmark *bookmark in myBookmarks) {
    NSLog(@"my UUID is %@",bookmark.uuid);
    NSLog(@"my title is %@",bookmark.title);
}
```

If you need to store these items in `NSUserDefaults` all you have to do is adopt the `NSCoding` protocol. If you don't know how to do it [here](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/Saving_Data/NSCoding.html) is a great and simple example.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I already have a Bookmark class with title, url and UUID encodings. Now it's a matter of proper sorting in an efficient manner.